# Unable to add a script to perforce triggers (change-submit)

Tags: perforce

I am trying to add a script to the `change-commit` trigger for perforce. But every time I make a change in the trigger form and save the file and goes back to command prompt, I get a message saying `Triggers not changed`.

What I have done is, executed the command `p4 triggers` and in the newly opened form added the trigger for running a python script.

Is there a way to see all the triggers that have been added for a server? Whenever I run `p4 triggers` the trigger section is always empty.

This must be a silly question, but I tried searching for an answer for a long time. But couldn't find any.

I am new to perforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you perhaps entering your trigger definition with a '#' sign at the start, which would make it a comment and seem like you hadn't changed the table at all?

To display the current triggers definitions, the 'p4 triggers -o' command will print the server's current triggers table to the screen.

Comment: I added the line newtrigger change-submit //depot/... "C:/Python27/python.exe A:/PerforceSubmitscript.py %changelist%" after Triggers: (without #). And saved the temp file. What should I do now. The command prompt is still showing p4 triggers.

Comment: Did you put it on the same line as "Triggers:"? Try putting your trigger definition on the next line, indented with a tab. Here's some docs: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4sag/chapter.scripting.html

Comment: I did it on the next line itself with one tab space before the entry. After editing , what should I do? The cmd prompt is still showing p4 triggers. I think it's not getting saved. It's still in the edit mode.

Comment: What type of editor are you using? The default editor Windows is Notepad, but perhaps you have configured a different editor? After adding your text to the triggers form, you need to save and exit from your editor.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a space (or TAB) at the start of your trigger line. I was tripped up by this for a good 30 minutes before seeing the "Trigger Definitions" example on this page:

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/p4sag/chapter.scripting.html

You'll see that each trigger is indented beneath the "Triggers:" heading.

Anyway, this worked for me.